# How disable creating new terms (tags)?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I am using drupal 6,How can I disable creating new terms during node submit?
Is there any option to do this? I do not see it in vocabulary settings.

I found, that Content taxonomy module have to do it, but I can figure how!
Thank you for your attention

Answer (score 0):

By default terms not add in drupal,Properly you  are using [active tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/active_tags) module,install [autocomplete_deluxe](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) module and use it as that field widget.

Comment: I forget. I am using Drupal 6